# Update using Entity Framework and MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

[Entities map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seWAX.png)
I'm having some trouble in executing a huge update in a mysql table using Entity Framework. What I want to do is a simple:
UPDATE client SET description = 'new description' WHERE id >=5. 
Here is the list of the nuGet packages installed:

> EntityFramework 6.2.0
>   MySql.Data 8.0.17
>   MySql.Data.Entity 6.10.9
>   MySql.Data.Entity 6.10.9
>   MySql.Data.EntityFramework 8.0.17
>   Z.EntityFramework.Extensions 4.0.5

I'm using MySql 8.0.17.
I'm using a ConsoleApp Framework 4.7.2.

Here is my code:

```
using ConsoleApp8.EFModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EFModel.georgeEntities dbContext = new EFModel.georgeEntities();
            dbContext.Database.Log = Console.Write;

            var result = dbContext.client.Where(x => x.id >= 5)
                                .UpdateFromQuery<client>(new Dictionary<string, object>() {{ "description", "New Value" }});
        }
    }
}
```

But all I get is an error:

Not handled exception : MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Table 'george.george.client' doesn't exist

What you must know is that 'george' is the schema name. Reading the error I think that the EntityFramework extensions is duplicating the schema name.

Someone has the same error as me using EntityFramework with Mysql or I'm using the wrong extensions library?

Thanks in advance for your help!
Interel

Comment: How did you generate your EntityFramework entities?
Can we see the entity map?

Comment: Hi, The EntityFramework entities was generated using Database first aproach (adding a new ADO.NET object, selecting tables, etc...). I have a .edmx in my solution, automatically generated (Entities map here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/seWAX.png)

Comment: I'm still wondering if I'm using the good extension for this. Have someone used already another nuget package to do what I need against a Mysql database?

Comment: ok, so no one is using bulk update in entity framework mysql........ :(